# Element animation on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

```
    <style>
    #first
    {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background:red;
    }
    #second
    {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background:blue;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
       <div id="first">
       </div>
    
       <div id="second">
          <h1 id="welcome">Welcome</h1>
       </div>

   </body>
```

What I want to achieve here is that on scrolling down the document I wanted the "h1 tag to fade in and appear as soon as I reach id="second". How to do that with JS. I have tried a couple of things, but nothing is working out the way I want. I also browsed regarding animation on scrolling and got results but I m not getting what's happening really. Can someone plz help me out in this? I m completely new to JS and trying out various kinds of stuff.
Thank you.

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the fade-in for multiple elements. Give a class to these elements and use the loop which is already commented.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        // $('.fadein').each( function(i){
            
            var bottom_of_element = $('#welcome').offset().top + $('#welcome').outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_element ){
                $('#welcome').animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
            }
            
        // }); 
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 600px
    
}
#first {
  background: red;
}

#second {
  background: green;
}
#welcome {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>h1 fade-in</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
         <div id="first">
       </div>
    
       <div id="second">
          <h1 id="welcome">Welcome</h1>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```